# How to connect to a remote mysql over ssh tunnel in spring boot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a spring boot application which is using mySQL db.DB is accessible on ssh via a different server.In Mysql Workbench i have created tunnel to access the mysql DB.

Now my question is there any way that i can do the same(tunnel over ssh) in my spring boot application? I have already searched on google but didn't get any fix for it.

If anyone can give an idea how to implement that would be really helpful.

Regards,

Comment: You have to connect from your applivcation to the tunnel start point on your side.

Comment: @JGK can you elaborate more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you are on a UNIX/Linux platform, the idea is that you do a

```
ssh -L 3306:mysql-server:3306 username@mysql-server
```

From within you spring boot application, you do a connect to `localhost:3306` which is forwarded to the `mysql-server` on port `3306`.

Doing it directly inside spring boot, you should go with [Java Secure Channel](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). An example for port forwarding is described [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingL.java.html).

Comment: this is not equivalent to doing ssh then logging. if we porform ssh and try to connect mysql server will receive user@localhost. but by this way it is receiving user@<mysqlserverIp/domain>

Comment: mysql is receiving user@mysql-server

Comment: I am facing an error of access denied for the user: user@mysqlserver Using Password Yes. I am able lo login to mysql using the same password.

Comment: The MySQL user must be able to access the MySQL DB from localhost.