# In Spring - How to connect to AWS RDS via a EC2 bastion host?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, bastion-host

I have a AWS RDS MySQL instance running, on a private subnet.
I have another EC2 instance running on a public subnet, which functions as a bastion host for the MySQL instance.
They are both in the same VPC.

I can connect to said instance via the mySQL workbench by configuring a Standard TCP/IP over SSH connection. I provide the SSH Hostname as the EC2 public IPv4 DNS, SSH Key file and the MySQL hostname and credentials.

I can't quite figure out how to connect to this db through a local springboot application. Any explanations would be helpful.

As in what should be the JDBC URL, and how do I get the application to route via the bastion host?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612459/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-mysql-over-ssh-tunnel-in-spring-boot-application/53627496

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296313/connect-to-mysql-through-ssh-and-by-using-spring-boot

Comment: Yeah I saw those other questions - thing is they don't give a very elegant solution, anyway to define a custom datasource with SSH tunnelling?